# Vagrant Up and annoying NFS password asking

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, sudo, nfs, vagrant

Sorry for the language mistakes I've made.
I'm trying to prevent vagrant asking the password when it mounts shared folders by NFS:

```
 [server] Exporting NFS shared folders...
 Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
 [sudo] password for timur: #!!!
```

I've red many online resources like github and other author's posts, but nothing work for me...

I tried the instructions was found [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1744#issuecomment-25512405). I don't have deep cli working knowledge. So could anybody give correct solution for my problem?

Comment: Could I kindly request to have the accepted answer now that this has been covered in the Vagrant docs?

Comment: First of all you need to check Is service `nfs-server` installed on your machine.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The official Vagrant docs now cover this: 
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html#root-privilege-requirement

You need to add entries to the `/etc/sudoers` file, and the way to edit that is to type this at the terminal: `sudo visudo`

Type your password, and you're editing the file.
You'll want to paste these lines below (depending on whether you are running Vagrant on OS X or Linux.

If you're not familiar with *vim*, which it opens in, [this page helped](http://maeks84.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/how-to-use-visudo/). Basically, copy the appropriate block of text below. Then, in visudo, go to the spot you want to paste text into the file (the end of the file is fine), and hit "i" to go into insert mode. CMD+V to paste your text. Then, hit ESC, then type `:w` to save your changes and then `:q` to quit.

**As of version 1.7.3**, the sudoers file in OS X should have these entries:

```
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD = /usr/bin/tee -a /etc/exports
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD = /sbin/nfsd restart
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE = /usr/bin/sed -E -e /*/ d -ibak /etc/exports
%admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD, VAGRANT_NFSD, VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE
```

And Linux should have these entries:

```
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_CHOWN = /bin/chown 0\:0 /tmp/*
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_MV = /bin/mv -f /tmp/* /etc/exports
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_CHECK = /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server status
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_START = /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_APPLY = /usr/sbin/exportfs -ar
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_EXPORTS_CHOWN, VAGRANT_EXPORTS_MV, VAGRANT_NFSD_CHECK, VAGRANT_NFSD_START, VAGRANT_NFSD_APPLY
```

Note that these change from one version of Vagrant to another, so the above might be outdated. The important thing is that the docs now cover it.

Comment: Weirdly this is not working for me, even though  `/var/log/auth.log` only contains commands which are listed there and I can manually verify that the sudo permissions are working.

Comment: Instead of editting the main sudoers file I recommend adding this as a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d` to avoid future conflicts when updating the OS. On Ubuntu: `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant-nfs` or OSX: `sudo visudo -f /private/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant-nfs`

Comment: This helped, thank you! Just a quick comment to your advice to get around *vim* editor: Just open visudo with `sudo EDITOR=nano visudo` command, which allows you to bypass *vim* completely.

Answer (score 2):

The exact commands can change between Vagrant versions, so it's impossible to list ones that would always work.

Anyway, the sudoers rules in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/beddari/1472018) should be still quite close. Check out /var/log/auth.log if it reveals the actual commands for your Vagrant version and adapt the rules accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this solution a long ago - it is doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone doing this for OSX (I'm on MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.6) I had a hard time with permissions even after adding those lines. This post really helped:

```
https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater/issues/50
```

Basicly its the fact that you dont have permissions set for the that folder yourself. So you need to run:

```
sudo chmod +a "$USER allow write,append" /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

adding `, nfs_export: false` at the end of the `config.vm.synced_folder`-lines in the Vagrantfile, solved it for me.

If you already have a working nfs-config, and don't need your Vagrant to overwrite it each time you start, then you can just disable the writing to the export-file.

This also solves the collision problem, if you have more then one Vagrant trying to access the same folder, as for example have 2 almost identical Vagrants, one running php 5.6 and one running php 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

TL&DR:  Add the following **override.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true**

Rational:  By default the Vagrant tries to detect any NFS / SMB folders.  While I can understand why the developers added this feature, for my use-case this is very annoying.  The solution is to simply DISABLE NFS folder syncing.

This can be done by overriding the VM synced folder option.  I have attached the following config for digital ocean for your consideration, so you can see the entire configuration.

```
 config.vm.define "droplet1" do |config|
 config.vm.provider :digital_ocean do |provider, override|
    override.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
        override.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
        override.vm.box = 'digital_ocean'=
        override.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant- 
 digitalocean/raw/master/box/digital_ocean.box"
    override.nfs.functional = false
            provider.image = 'ubuntu-14-04-x64'
            provider.region = 'nyc1'
            provider.size = '512mb'
       end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Gotta love "TL&DR" people! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to upvote ;)

Comment: Because of your "TL&DR" you deserve all the upvotes one can get, but truth is your answer didn't help me. Not because it's not good, but the problem I was having was slightly different from what was asked in the first place. Still, thank you for you good attitude. :)